opencv, mp4 not opening
I am starting to use openCV with python, and I recorded a video, when I open the video, windows tells me that I can't open it maybe because the type of file can't be taken or the extension (.mp4) can be wrong, so I tried to change it and it still didn't opened
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1080)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("recording.avi", fourcc, 30.0, (1080, 720))
recording = False

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)
        if recording:
                writer.write(frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    elif key == ord('r'):
        recording = not recording
        print(f"recording: {recording}")
    
cap.release()
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I tried with VLC media player too, still got nothing like the file is saved but it just dont play

Python 3.12.7 was successful for me. I changed the resolution from (1080, 720) to (640, 480). The resolution of my webcam is not 2K.

It works now I can succesfully watch the video I record with openCV thank you all

I am posting here the correction and I wanted to thank the two people wo answered to me,

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret:
    print("Captured frame resolution:", frame.shape)  # Check supported resolution

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frame.shape[1])
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, frame.shape[0])

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("recording.avi", fourcc, 30.0, (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]))

recording = False

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)
        if recording:
            writer.write(frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    elif key == ord('r'):
        recording = not recording
        print(f"recording: {recording}")

cap.release()
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Happy that you were able to resolve your issue.

@toyotaSupra Yes I know, but I don't think it really matters, It works like this so it's fine, I guess it's kind of irrevelent right now

The camera's resolution is not 1080 by 720 but 1280 by 720.
You can't request arbitrary video frame sizes from a camera, only those that it supports.
Check to make sure that frame.shape agrees with the frame size you promised to the VideoWriter.
